# How to calculate total distance between points covered by a Cab when my pickup and drop location are same?

Tags: ios, gps, mapkit, distance, cllocationmanager

I am working on some Cab related app. But I have a problem that if my pick up location and drop location are same then how can I calculate the distance covered by the cab that time.

Currently I am calculating distance from one coordinates to another coordinates using the below mentioned code.

```
func calculateDistance(pickLat: String, pickLong: String, dropLat: String, dropLong: String) {
    let coordinate0 = CLLocation(latitude: Double(pickLat)!, longitude: Double(pickLong)!)
    let coordinate1 = CLLocation(latitude: Double(dropLat)!, longitude: Double(dropLong)!)

    let distanceInMeters = coordinate0.distance(from: coordinate1) // result is in meters
    print(distanceInMeters)
}
```

This is normal process I am doing. Please help me out.

Comment: why don't you track whole route?

Comment: Track whole route...you mean to calculate the distance from time to time during the ride? or just to record all the lat longs for the complete route?

Comment: record all coordinates and use `locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) ` to respond to changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to work on specific event. You need to start capturing the location from your taxi app when the taxi arrived at pickup and the ride is started. You must have events like `ArrivedOnPickup` , `RideStarted`,`OnWay`, `Completed`.

Just like @Lu_ Suggested start capturing the coordinates in an array till the ride is completed. On ride completion you get the distance by implementing 
http://findnerd.com/list/view/How-to-calculate-distance-from-array-of-coordinates-in-iOS/17529/

> Note: You can also use [Google Direction](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) api to draw path and get the distance but this will not ensure that you route taken by the driver and route provided by the google will be same

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Working on the same.